# Increase salary of employees 1000 base on deparment avg highest salary

Tags: mysql

My employee table structure like below image

[image]

that below query get department id base on department average highest salary

```
SELECT dep_id
FROM employee
GROUP BY dep_id
ORDER BY AVG( salary ) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Output**

```
dep_id
2
```

but i having issue in update query

```
UPDATE employee
SET salary = salary +1000
where dep_id = (
SELECT dep_id
   FROM employee
   GROUP BY dep_id
   ORDER BY AVG( salary ) DESC
   LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: what is your `expected output`

Comment: @jack, i m getting that error You can't specify target table 'employee' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your current `SELECT` statement is it won't be able to get multiple `dep_id` having the same highest average `salary`. I'd rather do it this way to get the `dep_id`,

```
SELECT  dep_id
FROM    employee
GROUP   BY dep_id
HAVING  AVG(salary) = 
        (
            SELECT  AVG(salary) avg_sal
            FROM    employee
            GROUP   BY dep_id
            ORDER   BY avg_sal DESC
            LIMIT   1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6232/3)

then you can now update the `salary` for each `emp_id` having the highest average salary.

```
UPDATE  employee a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  dep_id
            FROM    employee
            GROUP   BY dep_id
            HAVING  AVG(salary) = 
                    (
                        SELECT  AVG(salary) avg_sal
                        FROM    employee
                        GROUP   BY dep_id
                        ORDER   BY avg_sal DESC
                        LIMIT   1
                    )
        ) b ON a.dep_id = b.dep_id
SET     a.salary = a.salary + 1000
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee1cc/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE employee e1
JOIN (SELECT dep_id, AVG(salary) avsal
      FROM employee
      GROUP BY dep_id
      ORDER BY avsal DESC
      LIMIT 1) e2
USING (dep_id)
SET e1.salary = e1.salary + 1000
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a06/1)

Comment: this will not support duplicate right? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f3ee0/3 (*i borrowed the fiddle from @JW웃*)

Comment: @SkyDrive You mean if two departments have the same highest average? It will pick one of them arbitrarily. That's what his original code tries to do, I didn't attempt to fix that. This just works around mysql's restriction on subqueries.

Comment: that code is work, but not work when more department have same highest avg salary

Comment: Your original code used `LIMIT 1` so I thought you only wanted to pick one department. JW 웃's answer is correct for multiple departments.